# Rewrite code android

Tags: android

I need help with my code that save image to device on android but images are not showing in gallery i tried a lot of different code but not working i need implement it to this code

```
public class SaveImage extends Activity {

    public void saveImage(ImageView imageView) {
        Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
        if(image != null && image instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image;
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Picster");
            dir.mkdirs();

            Date now = new Date();
            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(now);
            String path = dir.getPath() + File.separator;
            File file = new File(path + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");

            try {
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();

                galleryAddPic(file.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

public void galleryAddPic(String file) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(file);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
}
```

i call it in other activity like this

```
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.messageImageView);
    Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
    Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri.toString()).into(image);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SaveImage  cls2= new SaveImage();
            cls2.saveImage(image);

        }
    });
```

look on my updated code i add new void galleryAddpic and call it in TRY block it save pictures but still not show in gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add some lines of code to show that image in gallery with instant effect.

Add this code after your file has been created successfully.

**Code :**

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
```

**Example :**

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Request the media scanner to scan a file and add it to the media database.

[VISIT THIS LINK FOR MORE DETAILS](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery) :

Comment: @Gabriel add this lines after you create files.. means `File()` object has been created successfully.

Comment: @Gabriel you should add this in TRY BLOCK where you are writing to FILE. (FileOutputStream)

Comment: yes I know but need to add anything else? because of cannot resolve symbol MyMediaConnectorClient,context,setScanner another voids or include another class?